# How do you update a key's value from a widget?

Tags: thingsboard

I'm wondering if any Thingsboard dev's have tried to update a device's telemetry's key/value from within a widget.  If so how would you go about doing that?

Basically I have a widget that the end-user types a value into and I'd like the update a specific value associated with a key for a device with the user's input.

I know you could do a custom javascript POST command but if that's the case how do you read in the Device's access token from within the widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this *without* having to do a POST command.  From this post here: [Github Numeric Input modification widget](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/574) Basically, the widget updates the data key directly via Javascript and a device or entity's shared attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For saving/updating telemetry from the Widget you need to make a POST request to this REST API:

https://tb_address/api/plugins/telemetry/{entityType}/{entityId}/timeseries

**entityType** - DEVICE or ASSET

**entityId** - deviceId or assetId

**Swagger link:**
https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html#!/telemetry-controller/saveEntityTelemetryUsingPOST

---

**Body** (in a case when current system time should be used):

```
{
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

---

In cases when you want to **update (override) existing telemetry value**. You can use this body (the idea is the timestamp is a part of the composite key, so inserting with the same key will override previous value)

```
{
  "ts": 1451649600512,
  "values": {
    "key1": "value1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, I understand that I can do a POst Request from a custom widget but how do I read in the entityID from the widget's Javascript code? For example some data can be accessed with "${1}" but how do you get the current entityID?

Comment: You can find entityId in the subscription object (self.ctx.defaultSubscription). https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#latest-values-widget